# Boost Serialization: Serializing a tree with root memory management

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, tree

I have a custom tree data structure, and I've decided on the following setup. I have a `Tree` class with the ordinary pointers left, right, and upwards (parent), and then I have a `Root` class that inherits from `Tree`; the root class handles all memory management. (The tree needs to be fast so I cannot afford shared pointers). Every node in the tree exists in the memory pool at the root (and so `left()` will point inside the memory pool) as does each pointer to some `Data`:

```
class Root;

class Tree {

public:
    inline Tree() : mLeft(nullptr), mRight(nullptr), mParent(nullptr),
                       mRoot(nullptr), mData(nullptr) {}

    inline Tree *left()   { return mLeft; }
    inline Tree *right()  { return mRight; }
    inline Tree *parent() { return mParent; }
    inline Root *root()   { return mRoot; }
    inline Data *data()   { return mData; }

    inline bool isLeaf()  { return mData == nullptr; }

    ...

protected:
    inline Tree(Tree *parent, Root *root) :
        mLeft(nullptr), mRight(nullptr), mParent(parent), mRoot(root),
        mData(nullptr) {}

    Tree *mLeft;
    Tree *mRight;
    Tree *mParent;
    Root *mRoot;
    Data *mData;
};

class Root : public Tree {
    friend class Tree;
public:
    inline Root() : Tree(nullptr, this) {}
private:
    MemoryPool<Data> mDataSpace; // behaves like std::set for the purposes of this example
    MemoryPool<Tree> mNodeSpace;
};
```

The `Tree` class uses its `mRoot` reference to allocate new children nodes if I want to split a node for instance.

I now want to serialize the tree. Boost offers a very nice serialization library but I'm not sure how to fit it into my current setup. Ideally I would like to write:

```
template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version) {
        ar & mParent;
        ar & mRoot;        
    if (!isLeaf()) {
        left()->serialize(ar, version);
        ar & mLeft;
        ar & mRight;
        ar & mData;
        right()->serialize(ar, version);
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure this would work fine when saving, but what about loading? Each node needs to be allocated in `mDataSpace` before becoming the child of some other node. And what about the parent node? I don't think Boost's serialization is clever enough to realize these details without some extra work done first, right?

To further complicate things, the structure `Data` is immutable and I cannot write intrusive serialization for it. To serialize I can use `ar & data.x()` but to deserialize I need to write `data = Data(x);`.

I'm assuming I will have to write some sort of special constructor for `Tree` which allocates some space in the root node's memory containers for the `Tree` members `left` etc?

Perhaps Boost Serialization is not the ideal choice here? Thanks for any guidance or tips!

Comment: What purpose does the tree have? I'm tempted to write an alternative with the same memory localities but using Boost Intrusive. I'd need to know the semantics of the tree to choose the tree algorithms

Comment: It's a BSP tree. It's construction is quite complicated, but in essence each internal node stores a plane with an exact geometrical representation, and each leaf stores a complicated linked convex area structure. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Ah. I'm not qualified to suggest implementations there :| I personally go to `boost::geometry::indexing::rtree<>` for such tasks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're on the right track. To get Boost Serialization to instantiate the dynamic objects (Node/Data) you would implement

- `save_construct_data` and
- `load_construct_data`

You can read about this in the context of `Data` classes, which are not *default constructible*: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html#constructors

Now, for the central allocation, you *could* use the same. However, I suggest that it's probable much easier to simply serialize the `mDataSpace` and `mNodeSpace` containers, and serialize the indices into them instead of using boost to serialize all the tracked object references.

This will be less tricky and more efficient because Boost Serialization doesn't have to do the [Object Tracking](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/serialization/doc/special.html#objecttracking). What's more, you just have to make sure the Root is serialized *before* any of the nodes and you'll be fine.

#### Out Of The Box:

Thinking out of the box, I'd have implemented the very same thing but using Boost Intrusive to actually do the tree algorithms for me. Boost Intrusive containers actually don't own their elements, and the tree root is represented in pretty much the same way as you do here. So, you could have a tuple of the node-storage + the intrusive container, and have all the implementation details for free.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, it really helped! I think I'll try to serialize my MemoryPool. A question though; how do I properly call serialization for the MemoryPool's template parameter `T`, and also, is there a good way to convert the pointers to the indices you mentioned?